TabLayout with ViewPager2 but one tab is just a button
I am writing an application where I use TabLayout with ViewPager2. Each tab has a fragment in the ViewPager, the number of tabs may vary. I need to add a tab through the button located in the TabLayout as a separate tab, which does not have a fragment.
I tried to find a way to trigger clicking on a tab without calling select(), but I couldn't. All the tips that I found advised to disable OnTabSelectedListener() (which I use as a TabLayputMediator()), but then I lose the tabs that are already working. I also saw a tip using OnTouchListener() on a separate tab, but it requires calling view.performClick() by default, which leads to a select(tab) call.
Here's the part of the code where I'm trying to do this:
binding.apply {
    // Get data from room database
    groupsViewModel.allGroups.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { tasksGroups ->
        tasksGroups?.let { groups = it }

        tasksListContainerViewPager.adapter = TasksListViewPagerAdapter(requireActivity())
        TabLayoutMediator(tabLayout, tasksListContainerViewPager) { tab, position ->
            when (position) {
                0 -> tab.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_star_fill_24)
                else -> {
                    tab.text = groups[position - 1].groupTitle ?: "Group $position"
                }
            }
        }.attach()
        tasksListContainerViewPager.post {
            tasksListContainerViewPager.setCurrentItem(1, false)
        }
        
        // That separate tab
        val addGroupTab = tabLayout.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_add_24)
        tabLayout.addTab(addGroupTab)

        // FIXME: correct with warning (write my own separated OnSelectListener() ?)
        addGroupTab.view.isClickable = false
        addGroupTab.view.setOnTouchListener { _, _ ->
            showCreateGroupBottomSheet()
            false
        }

    }
}

Without this OnTouchListener(), when clicking on the addGroup tab, TabLayout will try to go to it, but since it does not have a fragment in the ViewPager, it will go to the last existing tab, which is the expected behavior of TabLayoutMediator, but not the desired behavior.
I also need my function to be called when clicking on this tab (which causes a dialog), while the content in the background remains the same.
I will be glad of any hints.
